# Play find("byEmail", email) not working in PostgreSQL 8.3

Tags: playframework

I've got a Play! app that I've been developing using an in-memory database, and now I'm switching to PostgreSQL so that I can deploy to Heroku.  I can connect to the database, and the tables get created properly.

I've got a class User as shown:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="dp_user")
public class User extends Model {
    @Email
    @Required
    public String email;
    ...       
    public static User findByEmail(String email) {
        return find("byEmail", email).first();    //line 55
    }
}
```

When `User.findByEmail` gets called, I get this:

```
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /login

Execution exception (In /app/models/User.java around line 55)
JPAQueryException occured : Error while executing query from models.User where e
mail = ?: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: Error while executing query <strong>from
 models.User where email = ?</strong>: ERROR: operator does not exist: character
 varying = bytea
        at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:90)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:257)
        etc.
```

I'm a little confused by the `<strong>` tags in the `JavaExecutionException`.  I don't see anything in my views that would cause this, but I think they're a red herring, and the real problem is some configuration issue related to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is your sql dialect setup correctly in application.conf? it should be jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Comment: `<strong>` is not a problem, it seems to be added in order to highlight the query if the message is displayed in a HTML page (`<strong>` == bold). Did you check your jpa.dialect, as suggested by emt14 ?

Comment: Ahah!  Thanks a lot emt14.  I know that I had that line in my conf before, but I lost it at some point while I was fiddling with other stuff.  Your suggestion fixed it!  Rephrase as an answer and I'll check it.